# Fancybox : The requested content cannot be loaded message on some items

Tags: fancybox

I have a website built in php codeigntier framework.

I have index page that's dynamically loading "li" elements and each "li" element has "a" tag which should display some item information via fancybox. Sometimes it is working, but sometimes it opens fancybox window, but instead of content it shows : "The requested content cannot be loaded message on some items".

Here is the code and after it i will explain what i did here:

index.php view (display page)

```
<li class="col-1-3">
        <h3>
            <a href="#"><?=$itm['name'];?></a>
        </h3>
        <figure class="full-width">
            <a id="inline" href="#data-<?=$itm['code']?>" class="inset-border zoom-hover" data-zoom-hover-title="Detalji">
                <img src="/slike/<?php echo $itm['img_name']?>" data-2x="/slike/<?php echo $itm['img_name']?>" width="124" height="150" alt="" />
            </a>
        </figure>
        <p>
            <b>Cena</b>: <?=$itm['price'];?> <br/>
            <b>Sifra</b>: <?=$itm['code'];?><br/>

            <b>PDV</b>: 19%
        </p>
        <b>Kolicina</b>: <input type="qty" class="qty-<?php echo $itm['id'];?>" name="qty" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" size="3" maxlength="3"/>

        <?php if($is_logged){?>
        <p>
            <a href="#_" class="buyButton big" name="<?php echo $itm['name'] ?>" id="<?php echo $itm['id'];?>" >
                <span>Dodaj</span>
                <i class="icon-plus color-blue"></i>
            </a>


        </p>
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <p>
            <a id="loged" href="$_" class="infoButton big">
                <span>Info</span>
                <i class="icon-info"></i>
            </a>
        </p>
        <?php } ?>
        <div style="display:none">
            <div id="data-<?=$itm['code']?>">
                <figure id="images" class="alignleft">
                    <img src="/slike/<?php echo $itm['img_name']?>" data-2x="/slike/<?php echo $itm['img_name']?>" width="250" height="350" alt="" />
                </figure>
                <h3><?=$itm['name']?></h3>
                <p><b>Cena Artikla:&nbsp; </b> <?=$itm['price']?> RSD<br/>
                    <b>Opis artikla:&nbsp; </b><?=$itm['descr'];?></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--<div style="display:none">
            <div id="log">
                <p>Morate biti ulogovani da bi ste kupili artikal</p>
            </div>
        </div>-->
    </li>
```

So,  dynamically adss data- ITEMID to every li item, and below

```
<div style="display:none">
        <div id="data-<?=$itm['code']?>">
            <figure id="images" class="alignleft">
                <img src="/slike/<?php echo $itm['img_name']?>" data-2x="/slike/<?php echo $itm['img_name']?>" width="250" height="350" alt="" />
            </figure>
            <h3><?=$itm['name']?></h3>
            <p><b>Cena Artikla:&nbsp; </b> <?=$itm['price']?> RSD<br/>
                <b>Opis artikla:&nbsp; </b><?=$itm['descr'];?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

has same ITEMID dynamically added.

So, by clicking on that , hidden info should display in fancybox... and it is working, sometimes.. sometimes not...

Here is my js file:

```
$("a#inline").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true
});
```

which is, of course, included in header of page, as fancybox.js file...

Any one has solution or suggestion ?

Thanks in advance.

p.s. you can visit poljoprivrednaapoteka.com and see the problem, just try clicking on few items, and the problem will pop..

Comment: Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support ==>FAQ tab ==> No. 6

Comment: I figured it out long time ago.. It was the image name problem, not the fancybox.. thanks tho